# Python: Why can't I unpack a tuple into a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, iterable-unpacking

Why doesn't this work?:

```
d["a"], d["b"] = *("foo","bar")
```

Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: I would have never even thought to try something like this ...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It would work if you define a dictionary `d` before hand, and remove the `*` from there:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d["a"], d["b"] = ("foo","bar")
```

In fact, you don't need those parenthesis on the RHS, so this will also work:

```
>>> d['a'], d['b'] = 'foo', 'bar'
```

Comment: Ahh, you don't need the *. Thanks.

Comment: @trideceth12: Out of curiosity, where did you get the idea for the `*`?

Comment: This is definitely cool (+1) -- [But I still assert `d.update(a='foo',b='bar')` is nicer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14854908/748858) :)

Comment: You also don't need the `()` on the RHS: `d['a'], d['b'] = 'foo', 'bar'`

Comment: @DavidRobinson I'd guess it may come from (in)famous *splat* operator of Ruby :-)

Comment: @DavidRobinson You need it to unpack tuples into function arguments

Answer (score 9):

Others have showed how you can unpack into a dict.  However, in answer to your question "is there a better way", I would argue that:

```
d.update(a='foo',b='bar')
```

much easier to parse.  Admitedtly, this doesn't work if you have `a` and `b` which are *variables*, but then you could use:

```
d.update({a:'foo',b:'bar'})
```

and I think I still prefer that version for the following reasons:

- It scales up to multiple (>2) values nicer as it can be broken onto multiple lines more cleanly
- It makes it **immediately** clear which key is associated with which value

And if you start off with a 2-tuple of values, rather than it being static as you show, you could even use `zip`:

```
d.update( zip(("a","b"),("foo","bar")) )
```

which is admittedly not as nice as the other two options ...

... And we've just covered all 3 ways you can use `dict.update` :).

Comment: This is really nice. Forgot about it. At least this will not get ugly when number of value increases. +1

Answer (score 0):

It's just a typo (the `*`). This works (tested in Python 2.7.3):

```
d = dict()
d["a"], d["b"] = ("foo", "bar")
```

Comment: It's not a typo. He used an unpacking operator which is used with lists and args. There is no need to use this operator when working with tuples. :)